# Google Structured Data Testing Tool does not show the Rich Snippets for video/publisher

Tags: microdata, google-rich-snippets

According to the Google Structured Data Testing Tool my Microdata code is correct. It verifies the PUBLISHER and the VIDEO. However in the preview it does not display the picture of the publisher or a thumbnail for the video.

Here is the code for the VIDEO:

```html
<div class="video-container">
<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
<h2><span itemprop="name">Learn Greek Online</span></h2>
<meta itemprop="duration" content="T52S" />
<meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PM7uvCZQNAs/hqdefault.jpg" />
<meta itemprop="embedUrl" content="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/PM7uvCZQNAs" />
<div id="schema-videoobject"><object width="640" height="380" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
<param name="src" value="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/PM7uvCZQNAs" />
<embed width="853" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/PM7uvCZQNAs" />
</object></div>
</div></div>
```

Here is the code for the PUBLISHER:

```html
<a href="https://plus.google.com/116607303426339665910" rel="publisher">xxx xxx</a>
```

This is the URL: http://learn-greek-online.com/

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Google's testing tool never displays an image for either the video thumbnail or the publisher in the results, if that's what you're referring to, bobptz.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was asking.  Thank you.

So how do I know I made everything correct?  

I used a tool to generate the code, but after using this validator, it gave me some erros and some warnings:  https://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml

I tried to fix the errors that were obvious.